# Weird issue with setting value via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've got this helper method **SetProperty** that sets the property of an object via reflection. Below, is 2 scenarios where I use that method. The first method **CreateInstance** works just fine, but the second method **Insert** doesn't work.

In the 2nd method, the property set on the object is lost as soon as the method **SetProperty** returns. I've debugged it via visual studio. The object has the property set uptill the last closing curly braces. Then as control is returned to the caller **Insert**, the Property value is lost.

**Method that sets properties**

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void SetProperty(object destination, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var type = destination.GetType();
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var convertedVal = Convert(value, property.PropertyType);

    property.SetValue(destination, convertedVal);
}
```

**The SetProperty method works fine in this method**

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>(SqlDataReader row, IEnumerable<CLASS> columns)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);

    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        SetProperty(obj, column.BackingPropertyName, column.Name);
    }

    return (T)obj;
}
```

**The SetProperty method doesn't work in this method**

```
public T Insert<T>(T obj, string table = null)
{
    // CODE CHUNK
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn))
        {
            // CODE CHUNK

            var autoGeneratedValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (temp.AutoGeneratedColumn != null)
            {
                ReflectionHelper.SetProperty(
                    obj,
                    temp.AutoGeneratedColumn.BackingPropertyName,
                    autoGeneratedValue
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

**EDIT - Add Console app to enable duplication**

***To replicate create new console app, then paste this code in Program.cs (Or equivalent)***

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public struct Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Person
            {
                ID = 93
            };

            var res = SetProperty<Person>(ref p, "Age", 34);
            Console.WriteLine(p.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(res.Age);
            Console.Read();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static T SetProperty<T>(ref T destination, string propertyName, object value)
        {
            var type = destination.GetType();
            var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            var convertedVal = Convert(value, property.PropertyType);

            property.SetValue(destination, convertedVal);

            return (T)destination;
        }

        private static object Convert(object source, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
            }

            if (destinationType.IsGenericType &&
                destinationType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
            {
                if (source == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                destinationType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(destinationType);
            }

            return System.Convert.ChangeType(source, destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a simple Console app?

Comment: Maybe you T in second example is struct so it is passed as value and after SetProperty you have old object?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, what do you mean by "reproduce in a console app". I've got this as a class library, I've also got some unit tests in place that allows me run into this case.

Comment: @blackcat, that's true. T is a struct.

I've thought of doing 2 things, first, returning the object that was passed in, second, passing the object using the ref keyword.

Comment: @ThatGuy I mean a minimal and complete repro that someone else could run, in order to investigate it.

Comment: pass object using ref keyword and it should work fine

Comment: @blackcat, passing with ref still exhibits the same behaviour. There's just something weird happening here. I've also tried returning the object that was set. This still isn't making any difference.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Have you added ref to SetProperty and Insert function?

Comment: @blackcat please see edit. I added a code snippet to allow you to replicate on your own machine.

Comment: @MatthewWatson , please see edit. I added a code snippet to allow you to replicate on your own machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your repro, I can see what the issue is.

This is being caused by your `Person` struct being boxed.

Consider this line of code in the `SetProperty<T>()` method:

```
property.SetValue(destination, convertedVal);
```

The first parameter of `SetValue()` is of type `object`. What that means is that when the struct `destination` is passed to it, it is boxed and the property is set on the boxed copy - leaving the original one unchanged. (Note that boxing only affects value types such as structs - if `Person` was a class, it wouldn't be boxed and it would work as expected.)

To fix this, you have to "manually" box the `Person` struct by assigning it to an `object`, then set the property on that object and finally assign it back to the original struct ref, like so:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static T SetProperty<T>(ref T destination, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var type = destination.GetType();
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var convertedVal = Convert(value, property.PropertyType);

    object boxed = destination;

    property.SetValue(boxed, convertedVal);

    destination = (T) boxed;

    return (T)boxed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, that's the secrete sauce. This whole boxing and unboxing can be confusing sometimes. Thanks once again.